# Android/Java: File.isFile- why not recognising file?

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent

In my `Android Activity` a message is displayed if `File.isFile()` is determine to be false. In this activity I want to `upload` a file to server that was created in the previous activity, its file name (to be added to path) is passed via an `intent` from previous to this activity.

Currently `File.isFile()` is `false`. What could cause this?

I think it could be that I am literally only creating the file and writing them to the storage on the device in the previous activity right before I try to upload it to server?

Below code is from the section where the file is checked:

```
//passed from previous activity as intent 
    fileNameRaw= getIntent().getStringExtra("fileNameRaw");
    final String uploadFilePath = "/storage/sdcard0/Math Game files/";

    sourceFileUri= uploadFilePath + fileNameRaw;

    final File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 


                  if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

                       dialog.dismiss(); 

                       Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                                            + sourceFileUri);

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                           public void run() {
                               messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                                        + fileName);
                           }
                       }); 

                       return 0;

                  }
```

Comment: Firstly, look into [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29) and make sure the usage is following it. And how use `exists()` method ???

Comment: Pl remove space from folder name it is bad practice. Also hard coding path like this "/storage/sdcard0/Math Game files/" is a bad practice. Instead you should use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() for getting external storage directory name.

Answer (score 0):

```
// passed from previous activity as intent
fileNameRaw = getIntent().getStringExtra("fileNameRaw");

final String uploadFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Math Game files/";

sourceFileUri = uploadFilePath + fileNameRaw;

final File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

if (!sourceFile.exists()) {

    dialog.dismiss();

    Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + sourceFileUri);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        }
    });


}
```

try this.It may help and avoid space the folder name.Thanks!

Comment: This has not solved the problem, I am still getting the same error